# Rinkeby faucet is not working

Tags: rinkeby

Hi i need ether for rinkeby network
But rinkeby faucet is not working please send me 2 eth on this address.
0xa53FCEe2aE984362fc730C9998595354F31a8431

Comment: Rinkeby has been deprecated, Goerli is now the only Ethereum testnet. You can get Goerli testETH here - https://goerlifaucet.com

Answer (score 1):

I use these:

https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby  (recommended)

The 2nd one I highly recommend because you can give yourself a couple ETH a day if you just do it several times. But go ahead and use both.

Edit: WOW it works now! I got 18 Eth. Gonna test out your findings @OP.

Answer (score 1):

For faucet on testnet use the [chainlink faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/).